# Azure cloud VM cannot send out email message using localhost and receive Delivery Status Notification (Failure)

Tags: smtp

We set up a VM in Windows Azure cloud service. However, the SMTP is not working. All the messages are queuing in the mailroot\queue folder. Here are some delivery failure message received.

Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550-5.7.1 [x.x.x.x] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to 550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
550-5.7.1 service provider instead.

Delivery Status Notification (Failure)
Action: failed
Status: 5.5.0
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 OU-002 (COL0-MC1-F41) Unfortunately, messages from x.x.x.x weren't sent. Please contact your Internet service provider since part of their network is on our block list.

How can it be solved? Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That looks to me as though the receiving hosts are blocking you from sending to them, probably because your IP is on a blocklist. You can check that on http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx

You might want to raise a support ticket with Azure and complain, and/or alternatively ask them for their SMTP server settings, which will relay the mail through their servers (which should never be blocked).